# Proving a set is neither open nor closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove that the set

$\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|0<y\le 1\right\}$

is neither closed nor open.

My book only has definitions (no examples) and I understand them but have no idea how to transfer them onto actual problems, so I'm struggling here. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Edit: Definitions:

A set $A$ is *open* if for all $\vec{x}$ $\epsilon$ $A$, there exists an $r > 0$ such that $B_r(\vec{x})$ $\subseteq A$ (where $B_r(\vec{x})$ is the open ball centered at $\vec{x}$ with radius $r$)

A set $A$ is *closed* if $A^c$ is open.

Comment: What are the definitions you've been given?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski made an edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $B_r(1)$.  You should notice for any $r>0$, $B_r(1)$ contains both point in $(0,1]$ and not in $(0,1]$.  This implies that neither $(0,1]$ or its complement are open.

Answer (score 3):

To prove the set (let's call it $S$) is not open, you need to find a point $x$ in $S$ such that no open ball $B_r(x)$ is contained in $S$.

To prove the set $S$ is not closed, you have to show $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash S $ is not open. So again you look for a point in $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash S $ such that any open ball around it is not fully contained in $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash S $.